# How to repair all indexes in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search

My database got corrupted, and now the php app is throwing this error:

```
Invalid query: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

The error is not very useful, since it doesn't say what column/table is causing it.
Is there a way to regenerate FULLTEXT indexes on all columns in all tables within a specific database?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should look for all tables that have fulltext indexes

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE index_type='FULLTEXT';
```

To individually remake all tables that have FULLTEXT indexes

```
REPAIR_SQL_SCRIPT=RemakeTables.sql
SQL="SELECT"
SQL="${SQL} CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',db,'.',tb,' ENGINE=',eng,';')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM (SELECT A.table_schema db,A.table_name tb,B.engine eng"
SQL="${SQL} FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table_schema,table_name"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_type='FULLTEXT') A"
SQL="${SQL} INNER JOIN information_schema.tables B"
SQL="${SQL} USING (table_schema,table_name)) AA"
mysql -uroot -ANe"${SQL}" > ${REPAIR_SQL_SCRIPT} 
cat ${REPAIR_SQL_SCRIPT}
```

If you are OK with the contents of `RemakeTables.sql`, then execute it:

```
mysql -uroot < ${REPAIR_SQL_SCRIPT}
```

**CAVEAT** : All indexes are remade as well

Comment: Your script is great, but there is a slight issue: If a database name or a table name contain special characters such as a dot (.) in the database name then the generated alter table SQL command will fail. Here is a simple fix for this issue, just change this line: SQL="${SQL} CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',db,'.',tb,' ENGINE=',eng,';')" to this: SQL="${SQL} CONCAT('ALTER TABLE \`',db,'\`.\`',tb,'\` ENGINE=',eng,';')"

Answer (score 0):

This are the quick steps to fix the corruption:

**Step 1**

Using telnet, ssh, or a local machine, connect to the mySql server and log into the mySql command-line tool. This can be done with mysql -p.

**Step 2**

Use the CHECK TABLE tablename FOR UPGRADE command to verify the table needs to be repaired.

**Step 3**

Exit the mysql command-line tool by typing x and pressing the "Enter" key. You will return to the shell command prompt.

**Step 4**

Dump the table with the mysqldump command: mysqldump databaseName tableName > dump.sql.

Re-create the table in the database with the mysql command: mysql databaseName < dump.sql. This will rebuild the table and the table indexes.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as it assumes the problem table name is known, which is not the case in the original question.

Comment: one of my friend got this post while searching the solution to repair the index. The solution suggested by me could be helpful for other users who are facing this problem. this post is 7 years old and I hope ddraio fixed it.